# Push one object to another inside JSON

Tags: javascript, json

So for example I have object like this:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: 13,
      name: "id13"
    },
    {
      id: 21,
      name: "id21"
    }
  ],
  included: [
    {
      id: "13",
      badge: true
    },
    {
      id: "21",
      badge: false
    }
  ]
}
```

And now I need to loop over included and push included to data where id is equal.

So after transformation it would have badge in data, for example like this:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: "13",
      name: "id13",
      included: {
        id: "13",
        badge: true
      },
    },
    {
      id: "21",
      name: "id21",
      included: {
        id: "21",
        badge: false
      }
    }   
  ]
}
```

of course I tried on my own and I've created this code:

```
for(let i=0; i<includedLength; i++) {
  console.log(a.included[i].id);
  for(n=0; n<dataLength; n++) {
    console.log(a.data[n]);
    if(a.icluded[i].id === a.data[i].id) {
      console.log('We have match!!!');
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work I have an error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

This is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/192a7tv3/) of my code.

Comment: Hi man look at your code u check a.icluded[i].id . U missing char

Comment: [That is *not* JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: There are so many typos in your code. Correct them first. For example, you have typed `icluded` instead of `included`. Aren't you using an IDE or a standard text editor for coding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All solutions here have gone in the same path as you had, which is not efficient. So I am posting my solution, which is more efficient than the other solutions so far. Read the code comments to understand the optimizations done.

```
// Convert data array into a map (This is a O(n) operation)
// This will give O(1) performance when adding items.
let dataMap = a.data.reduce((map, item) => {
    map[item.id] = item;
    return map;
}, {});

// Now we map items from included array into the dataMap object
// This operation is O(n). In other solutions, this step is O(n^2)
a.included.forEach(item => {
    dataMap[item.id].included = item;
});

// Now we map through the original data array (to maintain the original order)
// This is also O(n)
let finalResult = {
    data: a.data.map(({id}) => {
        return dataMap[id];
    })
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResult))
```

Comment: No need for parseInt. Objects can't have numeric keys and when used will always be cast to string. `obj[1] === obj["1"]`

Comment: @charlietfl I learned that today. Thanks. I will update the answer

Comment: I edited object and your code a bit and now it is working only for first element and converting second one to null. Why? https://jsfiddle.net/192a7tv3/8/ Sorry for this but I'm still trying to understand.

Comment: I mean why it convert second one to null?

Comment: @BT101 That's because you have a typo in the code. (Instead of 22, you have typed 21)

Comment: Yes because now I'm taking ID from other place `map[item.relationships.game.user.id] = item;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, this will provide the required output!

It constains the same standard for loops.

Some points I would like to highlight are,

1. The `id` in `included` property is string, so you can use the `+` operator to convert it to number.
2. The `Object.assign()` method is used so that we create a new copy of the corresponding object. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var data = {
  data: [{
      id: 13,
      name: "id13"
    },
    {
      id: 21,
      name: "id21"
    }
  ],
  included: [{
      id: "13",
      badge: true
    },
    {
      id: "21",
      badge: false
    }
  ]
}

var output = {
  data: data.data
};

for (var q of data.included) {
  for (var j of output.data) {
    if (+q.id === j.id) {
      j['included'] = Object.assign({}, j);;
    }
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console {
  height: 100%;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not a JSON, its an Object. A valid json consists of both its key and value as string. What you are trying to do is manipulate an object. The following code should help in getting the desired output.

```js
const obj ={
  data: [
    {
      id: 13,
      name: "id13"
    },
    {
      id: 21,
      name: "id21"
    }
  ],
  included: [
    {
      id: "13",
      badge: true
    },
    {
      id: "21",
      badge: false
    }
  ]
}

for (var i=0; i<obj.data.length;i++){
  for(var j=0; j< obj.included.length;j++){
  if(obj.data[i].id == obj.included[j].id){
   obj.data[i].included={
    id: obj.included[j].id,
    badge: obj.included[j].badge
    }
  }
  }
}

delete obj.included

console.log(obj)
```

What I am doing her is:

1. Checking if id of obj.data is equal to that of obj.included
2. If they are equal add a new key called "included" in obj[data]
3. When the loop is over delete the "included" key from obj as its not required anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a waste of space to push the whole "included" element into the first array when a match is found (you really need that extra id element in there?) - so this just makes output like

```
[{id: 1, name: 'name', badge: true},{...}]
```

If no matching badge element is found, it sets badge to false.

```js
var notJSON = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 13,
      name: "id13"
    },
    {
      id: 21,
      name: "id21"
    }
  ],
  included: [
    {
      id: "13",
      badge: true
    },
    {
      id: "21",
      badge: false
    }
  ]
};

var badged = notJSON.data.map(function (el, i) {
  el.badge = notJSON.included.find(function (inc) {
    return inc.id == el.id;
  }).badge || false;
  return el;
});

console.log(badged);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 13,
      name: "id13"
    },
    {
      id: 21,
      name: "id21"
    }
  ],
  included: [
    {
      id: "13",
      badge: true
    },
    {
      id: "21",
      badge: false
    }
  ]
};

obj.included.forEach((item) => {
    obj.data.forEach(item1 => {
    if(item.id == item1.id){
        item1.included = item;
    }
  });
});
delete obj.included;
```